# Unable to get tab bar from react-navigation working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I want to show tab bar in my `react-native` app using `react-navigation` library. I've tried code from an [example provided in the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html). However, when I run the code on iOS simulator the screen appears to be blank, tab bar doesn't load.

Here's my code so far,

**TabNavigator.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {  
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }  
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import TabNavigator from './components/TabNavigator';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TabNavigator />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the App.js code, you forgot to put flex:1 to the view, it's one of the common mistakes that `react-navigation` tells about in his documentation.

```
 const App = () => {
      return (
       <View style={ { flex:1} }>
         <TabNavigator />
       </View>
      );
    };
```

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html#wrapping-appcontainer-in-a-view-without-flex